# Конструкция if..else с отрицательным условием

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, прояснить ситуацию. Есть конструкция вида:

```
var status = 'medium';

if(status != 'strong' || status != 'medium'){
    console.log('легкий пароль');
}
```

Мне нужно вывести пользователю предупреждение, если он указал легкий пароль.

Я дословно читаю ее: "Если переменная `status` НЕ равна `strong`, либо НЕ равна `medium`, то вывести в консоль сообщение". В данном случае, при том, что переменная равна одному из условий, все равно выводится сообщение в консоль. Я не знаю почему, ведь конструкция в скобках представляется собой одно целое выражение. По крайней мере `status != 'medium'` должен возвращать `false`.

Вот то, как для меня это должно работать:

```
if(status == 'strong' || status == 'medium'){

}else{
    console.log('легкий пароль');
}
```

Как переписать это выражение с одним условием без `else`, где `status` не должен быть равен либо `strong`, либо `medium`?

Comment: Оператор `||` возвращает первое значение `true` (status != 'strong'), остальные значения игнорируются.

Comment: Ничего удивительного: `status != 'strong'` -> true, `status != 'medium'` -> false. `true || false` -> true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (status != 'strong' && status != 'medium') {
```